# gradle to create multiple war files from folders

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, war

My Gradle project doesn't contain any classes or other configurations. It contains a folder called `ExternalLibs` containing other folders. 
I need to create a war file for each folder present in `ExternalLibs` and place it in `lib` folder.

Thanks for the help.

Folder structure:

```
 Project Root
   |-- ExternalLibs
         |-- analyst
         |-- storageService
         |-- retrievalService
```

Exepcted output:

```
 Project Root
   |-- lib
        |-- analyst.war
        |-- storageservice.war
        |-- retrievalService.war
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task of type `Zip`, since `War` archive is a `Zip` with a fancy extension. You have to create a task per `War`, but you can automate it by creating tasks dynamically:

```
List folders = new File(projectDir, "ExternalLibs").listFiles();
folders.each { dir ->
    task "zip${dir.name}"(type: Zip) {
        from dir
        include '**/*'
        destinationDir new File("$projectDir/lib")
        archiveName "${dir.name}.war"
    }
}
```

To run all tasks at once, you can create a task that depends on all of them:

```
task allZips { }
allZips.dependsOn tasks.withType(Zip)
```